# Ruta show no definida en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

estoy presentando el siguiente error de: Route [quotations.show] not defined. (View:, al realizar un route:list me he dado cuenta que la ruta show no aparece no solo para quotations si no tambien para role y user, a pesar de si estar definidas en el archivo web.php

```
 Route::post('admin/quotations/store','QuotationController@store')->name('quotations.store')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.create');

    Route::get('admin/quotations','QuotationController@index')->name('quotations.index')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.index');

    Route::get('admin/quotations/create','QuotationController@create')->name('quotations.create')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.create');

    Route::put('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@update')->name('quotations.update')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.edit');

    Route::get('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@show')->name('quotations.show')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.show');

    Route::delete('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@destroy')->name('quotations.destroy')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.destroy');

    Route::get('admin/quotations/{quotation}','QuotationController@edit')->name('quotations.edit')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.edit');
```

seccion en la vista :

```
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Cotizaciones
                    @can('quotations.create')
                        <a href="{{route ('quotations.create')}}" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear</a>
                    @endcan
            </div>  
            <div class="card-body">
              <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead class="table table-primary">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Codigo</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Detalle</th>
                            <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($quotations as $quotation)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$quotation->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$quotation->client->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$quotation->created_at}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                          @can('quotations.show')
                                            <a href="{{route ('quotations.show,$quotation->id')}}" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear</a>
                                        @endcan
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

Las rutas otras 6 rutas por modulo si funcionan.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tenés definidas 2 rutas iguales:

```
Route::get('admin/quotations/{quotation}', 'QuotationController@show')
    ->name('quotations.show')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.show');

Route::get('admin/quotations/{quotation}', 'QuotationController@edit')
    ->name('quotations.edit')
    ->middleware('can:quotations.edit');
```

La ruta del `edit` debería ser `admin/quotations/{quotation}/edit`.

---

Ahora, no se como estás implementando los `middlewares`, pero tal vez sería más simple utilizar [resourceful routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers) para definir las rutas y utilizar [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-controller-helpers) para los controladores.

**web.php:**

```
Route::resource('quotations', 'QuotationController');
```

Después generás las `policies` con:

> php artisan make:policy QuotationPolicy --model=Quotation

Eso te va a generar un archivo con reglas para todos los métodos (view, create, update y delete). Es probable que lo que tenés en los middlewares lo puedas trasladar al policy.

**QuotationController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Quotation;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class QuotationController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Quotation::class, 'quotation');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

El unico error que veo esta en:

```
<a href="{{route ('quotations.show,$quotation->id')}}" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear</a>
```

que deberia de ser:

```
 <a href="{{route ('quotations.show',$quotation->id)}}" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear</a>
```

si notas la comilla que cierra esta mal.

Comment: Entonces es un error tipográfico y no debería ser una respuesta, debería ser un comentario y cerrarse la pregunta.

Comment: No es un error tipografico, sigue diciendo el mismo error haciendole route:list no muestra la ruta creada es como que no existiera a pesar de si estar definida en el archivo web.php

Comment: @RafaelArguelles, deberias de intentar crear otro proyecto, en todo caso muestra una foto de route:list. yo borrare la respuesta en unas horas ya que este no soluciono tu problem

Comment: Al hacer route:list no muestra la ruta creada, a pesar de estar definida en el archivo web.php, ni en la seccion de quotations ni en roles ni en users, a pesar de estar definidas para los 3